# set imageview hide and visible programically

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have image-view in my layout . I want if there is any image in my database , make my image-view visible , else make my image-view gone.
My image-view have special size in layout , when there is no any image , the space of image-view exist and it is empty although my is image-view is gone.

here is my layouts:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addbtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_matn_img"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_matn_matn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

>

and here is how to check for visible & visible.

```
  String p = db.getpic("tbl_book", sea, Name, page3 + "");

    if (p != null) {
        int ImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(p, "drawable", getPackageName());
        img.setImageResource(ImageResource);
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

by this way if I don't have any picture , it showws my imageview size , although is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_matn_img"

                    android:visibility="visible"
</ImageView>


     String p = db.getpic("tbl_book", sea, Name, page3 + "");
        if (p != null && p.length()>0) {
 img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int ImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(p, "drawable", getPackageName());
            img.setImageResource(ImageResource);


        } else {
            img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: I check this , but nothing is changed . I have to give static size to my imageview and that is problem .. I really don't know what should I do ?

Comment: @balvin Do one thing change the initial visibility of main_matn_img to visible and handle visibility through the code.

Answer (score 0):

**First way:**

**You have to use `wrap_content` in your imageView :**

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_matn_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

**Second way :**

you can handle it programitically like this:

```
 String p = db.getpic("tbl_book", sea, Name, page3 + "");

    if (p != null) {
        int ImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(p, "drawable", getPackageName());
        img.setImageResource(ImageResource);
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
img.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
            img.getLayoutParams().width=100;

    } else {
  img.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
            img.getLayoutParams().width=0;
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: No I have to give size to my imageview .

Comment: If you use static size , you cant solve your problem, maybe you can set your imageView between relativeLayout and set static size to relaytiveLayout and set wrap_content to your imageView.

Comment: so if i do this , i should make my relativeLayout visivble and gone . what is the diffrence ? Can I speak persian ? I think that you can too.

Comment: I think you can do it programitically too ,i added.